# Pausing in C++ - Which Method?

Tags: c++, sleep, thread-sleep

I've noticed two different ways to "pause" in C++. (Though I think the proper name for it is `sleep`ing.)


Method 1, (probably the method most are familiar with):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
  std::cout<<"Hello, "<<std::endl;
  sleep(1);
  std::cout<<"world!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

And the method I learned first:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
int main() {
  std::cout<<"Hello, "<<std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  std::cout<<"world!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

I'm not asking which way is *right*, (they both do the same thing), but rather I'm asking which is more *used*, or *"accepted"*. Also, is there a difference between these two when it comes to things like speed/performance?

Comment: "is there a difference between these two when it comes to things like speed/performance?" - you are suspending execution for an *entire second*. Performance is out the window right there.

Comment: Best bet is not to pause. There is  almost never any need to do it, and it's bad UI design because the user can't skip the pause.

Comment: As long as you don't mind limiting your code base to C++11 or higher `std::this_thread::sleep_for` is 100% portable in that enviroment  while `sleep` isn't.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk: The surrounding `extern` does not hurt, but is not necessary. Most headers enable it by default when `__cplusplus` is defined.

Comment: In production code, a sleep frequently indicates that someone had a problem in their code that was avoided by allowing another process a "little more time" to finish what it was doing.  A sleep is a red flag which points the developer to investigate why the sleep was helpful in the first place.  As @NeilButterworth indicated, there is rarely a good reason for it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth "There is almost never any need to do it" Unless when this is exactly what you need, which happens surprisingly often. Sure, freezing interactive UI is bad, but I don't see anyone trying that (the example is not interactive).

Comment: @Frax Anything that displays output on a screen is interactive.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Of course not. _Interactive_ means _allowing a two-way flow of information between a computer and a computer-user; responding to a user’s input_.  There is no place for user input or action, therefore this program is not interactive.

Comment: @Frax Ctrl-C, click the `X` button. These are interactive, but terminate the program (sending signals to it) , but don't skip the pause, which was my original point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference between these two methods is the portability:

- `sleep` from `unistd.h` is part of the C POSIX Library and therefore only available on Systems that provide the POSIX-API (e.g. Linux, BSD, ...) but for example not on Windows
- `std::this_thread::sleep_for` is part of the C++ Standard Library (since C++11) and is therefore available on all platforms that support C++11 and newer

If you have the choice use `std::this_thread::sleep_for` to rely only on a C++11 implementation and not on the System API.

Comment: I'd add a second difference is granularity. `sleep()` can sleep only for *seconds* -- whole seconds. `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` can potentially get down to *microseconds*. Though there's also `usleep()`, which is also not portable.

Answer (score 3):

Primary differences:

- `std::this_thread::sleep_for` is a standard function (since C++11). `sleep` is a POSIX standard function, and so is only available on systems that support POSIX.
- The unit of the argument of `sleep` is seconds, while `std::this_thread::sleep_for` allows the use of any `std::chrono::duration` (although the clock used for measurement will have its own granlarity that may be less precise than the time that you specify).
- The behaviour of `std::this_thread::sleep_for` is not defined in relation to signals that may interrput program flow. Typically, `std::this_thread::sleep_for` will be interrupted prematurely just like `sleep` would be, but there is no easy way of finding out how much time was left to sleep. `sleep` on the other hand returns the time left to sleep, so it is easy to deal with interruptions using a loop that sleeps until returned time to sleep is zero.